# Turkish New Driver's License

Tags: eu

I was issued a new driving license in Turkey. Could I use my new Turkish Driver's License to rent a car in Portugal from Avis?

Comment: Any particular reason for Avis and not one of the European companies?

Answer (score 1):

My suspicions would be, Yes.  I tried to find the answers on-line but did not find it.  So I suggest you call them.  They have phone numbers in Turkey and in Portugal:

[European Numbers](https://www.avis.com/car-rental/content/display.ac?navId=T5M13S04)